# GROUP BY sql with join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm still new to joins.

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id,a.code,a.name_a,sb.name_sb 
        FROM activites a JOIN 
             Sous_branche sb 
             ON a.sous_branche_id = 2 
        GROUP BY a.id";
```

When I took off the `GROUP BY` it works but it shows me the data duplicated. For this I used the `GROUP BY` to structured them. But it shows this error:

> POST
>   http://localhost/excel_branche/requetes/Selection/Models/UneSBranche_model.php
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: If you want to get rid of duplicated _rows_, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate entries :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.code, a.name_a, sb.name_sb 
FROM activites a JOIN 
     Sous_branche sb 
     ON a.sous_branche_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a function such as `SUM` , group by using a field in the SELECT list is useless. If you want to remove duplicate data use `SELECT DISTINCT` option.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.code,a.name_a,sb.name_sb 
        FROM activites a JOIN 
             Sous_branche sb 
             ON a.sous_branche_id = 2";
```